# GitHub not showing activity?

Tags: github

My [GitHub account](https://github.com/ablaszkiewicz) shows that my latest contribution was on March 21st.
When you head to [commits](https://github.com/ablaszkiewicz/kiedy-kolos/commits/New-Backend-Integration) section, you can see that I did commit today and yesterday.

Why isn't it shown in my activity?

Also - for quite a long time I have been commiting to projects from my work-account not realising that it makes me last contributor in my own project :D. Is there a way to link this email (work) with my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first the "[Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#commit-was-not-made-in-the-default-or-gh-pages-branch)":

> Commits are only counted if they are made in the default branch or the gh-pages branch (for repositories with project sites).
>
> If your commits are in a non-default or non-gh-pages branch and you'd like them to count toward your contributions, you will need to do one of the following:
>
> - Open a pull request to have your changes merged into the default branch or the gh-pages branch.
> - Change the default branch of the repository.

And you were committing on the [non-default branch `New-Backend-Integration`](https://github.com/ablaszkiewicz/kiedy-kolos/commits/New-Backend-Integration).

Also, the username/email used is important: you can [add emails to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account).

Comment: What if I'd like to squash my commits from that branch? In this case I'll only have 1 commit out of for instance 15 commits that were made on my feature branch.

Comment: @Miraziz That is likely indeed. I suppose this is how it is working at the moment for GitHub.